# Threads and Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Hello stackoverflow users. I don't know if i found a bug in android (probably not but it looks like so for me). Straight to the problem  - when im using thread or try-catch in my code, activity is not executing the thread/try-catch part unless i swipe navigation drawer from left and then it runs thread/try-catch for ridiculously short amount of time and doesn't even have time to do what it has to do. Can someone explain to me how to overpass this problem and why it is not working in the first place?

```
public class ServerStatus extends Activity {
String[] menu;
DrawerLayout dLayout;
ListView dList;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
Context context;
String o=null;
static class Data {
    String name;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_server_status);
    menu = new String[]{"Not yet working"};
    dLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    dList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menu);
    dList.setAdapter(adapter);
    context=getApplicationContext();
    TextView a = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.EUNE);



    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            o="test";  //I set string to anything
        }
      }).start();

    a.setText(o);// and here i get nothing because it was executed before swiping navdrawer obviously




dList.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);
    dList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
    dLayout.closeDrawers();
    if(position==0)
    {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
    });}
```

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Why do you need the thread?

Comment: I need to refer to other function and then i have to use try catch. I discovered that threads have similar problem so I wrote about them too.